# Why are some Android Versions unchecked in my Google Developer Console?

Tags: android, statistics

I see the following under "Statistics" for my Android App in [Google Developer Console](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fplay.google.com%2Fapps%2Fpublish%2F&ei=O3tLVLqqJIihyQSGqoLAAw&usg=AFQjCNEvG-AI0sojdmEeraO9D_b4Xtsn6g&sig2=V2-pm0gfyR-oYHdAs_DyKA&bvm=bv.77880786,d.aWw). My question is - why are some App versions unchecked when I open this page?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The checked versions are the only one visible in the graph above - which by default lists the current installs by Android version:

[image]

If you check more versions, it will show up in the graph as well.

Comment: does this mean that the versions that are unchecked were downloaded at some point - but current all active installs are only on devices that are checked?

Comment: Nah, my guess is that just only the top 3 versions are checked, to avoid clutter the graph too much. I don't think there is a specific reason.